# telebot consumes a huge amount of memory after sending photo

Tags: python, memory-management, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I have produced a telegram bot using python and telebot module. My bot is supposed to send photos when it recieves commands from users. The problem is sending each photo consumes 10MB of my computer memory and I don't know how to free up memory after sending each photo. I'm using the following command to send photos.

`bot.send_photo(cid, photo=open(save_name, 'rb'))`

Comment: One line of code will not give any hint about the memory leak. Add enough code to reproduce it (and test that before posting).

Comment: I have checked up every single line. This is the line that produces extra cache

Comment: try explicitly closing the file. e.g. you can open the file via a context manager (`with open … as file:` or use the `pathlib` module (`Path(save_name).read_bytes()`)